# How could Jigsaw afford to build all those traps?

Tags: saw

In the *Saw* movies Jigsaw is poor guy, so how he could purchase all the materials and equipment required to build traps?

Some traps are very heavy and Jigsaw is cancer patient, so how did he build traps himself? And, if he used some help, how did he afford to pay their salaries?

Traps were built into houses, and houses cost a lot of money. How could he purchase all those houses?

Some traps are very sophisticated and would require very sepcial equipment to be built, not something that a poor cancer patient can purchase.

Comment: You need to watch the series.  Some of this gets explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here, so I'll try to break them down one by one:

1. How could Jigsaw afford to build all those traps and How did he build the traps?

[John Kramer (Jiggsaw)](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/John_Kramer) was actually successful Civil Engineer and founder of the [Urban Renewal Group](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Urban_Renewal_Group), so he had access to money as well as the know-how to assemble the various traps. He is particularly skilled in creating clockwork and actually created the [famous puppet](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Billy_the_Puppet) long before he ever took up the mantle 'Jigsaw'

2. How did he get help for his traps?

John Kramer is known to enlist lackeys, either through blackmail or by attracting people who shared his vision ([Amanda Young](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Amanda_Young)). It's rarely the case that he needed to pay for the help he received.

3. Traps were build in houses, which cost money, where did he get the money?

As noted in #1, John Kramer had money; it's also worth noting that the houses used for traps are typically abandoned, or in areas with low land value, so it wouldn't have taken much money to acquire these properties.

Comment: You can LITERALLY buy a house in parts of Detroit for $1.  I mean, no one would want to live in them and they're probably devoid of any and all plumbing/wiring, but you can still buy one for a buck.

Comment: Keeping Amanda aside his other followers had talents too for helping in the traps